# Do anchor tag labels need to be unique in DocuSign envelopes?

Tags: docusignapi

Does an anchor tag identifier (label) need to be unique to the entire document?
Do anchor tag identifiers (labels) need to be unique for all documents in an envelope?

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction for the anchor tags, however keep in mind that every time the anchor is found the appropriate element is placed.  So if you tie a signature to "the" and an initial to "them" you will get duplicates because "the" is a substring of "them".

It's best to keep the anchors unique to a particular recipient and element type such as:

```
<s1> -Signature for Signer1
<i1> - Initial for Signer1
<d2> - date for Signer2
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I need additional clarification on anchor tag uniqueness for the following scenario: Duplicate anchors submitted on a document that requires the first signer to electronically place the same signature, initials and date twice on a page. 

<s1> -Signature for Signer1  
<i1> - Initial for Signer1   
<d2> - date for Signer1  

<s1> -Signature for Signer1  
<i1> - Initial for Signer1  
<d2> - date for Signer1  


I would also need to get clarification on placing the same anchors on multiple pages within a document.

Comment: What's actually your question?  The tags will be placed as many times as the string is found.  It's a simple operation of looking for a string and putting the tag there on any page.  I hope this helps clarify the way it works.

Comment: @mikebz So, if I have a document that has six locations, tagged on page 3 as <i1#1>, <i1#2>, <i1#3>, <i1#4>, <i1#5>, and <i1#6>, and I submit six Tabs in my envelope (through the SOAP api) for signer1 to initial at each of these AnchorTags, are you saying that I would get exactly the same result if I replaced each of those tags with <i1> and just submitted one signature Tab with the AnchorTag <i1>? Six distinct signature objects are created?

Comment: yes.  Any time the string is found the signature would be placed